# Correlative comparative: in "The + comparative adjective + the + noun + ..." what is the role of the second "the"?

Tags: definite-article, correlative-constructions

I have come across this piece of writing:

[image]

The final sentence is:

> 1 The wider the range of skills one has, the greater **the** opportunities there will be.

The second "the" before "opportunities " sounds awkward to me. I think if we omit it, it is more natural. Could you please explain why the writer has used it here? Have they used it here correctly? Can we dispense with it?

---

I have also seen other examples of this structure:

> 2 The more carefully we consider how we discipline children, the brighter **the** futures they will have.

> 3 The greater **the** cost, the greater **the** financial stress is to the students.

> 4 The more governments invest in the future, the greater **the** rewards they will reap in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The greater the opportunities** suggests both the extent of the opportunities and the number.

More importantly, it's the more idiomatic construction as the inclusion of the second **the** serves to balance the insertion of the article in **the range of skills**.

**The greater opportunities**, omitting the article, is also possible but it lacks the rhythmic balance and sounds less convincing.

Comment: It's idiomatic. "the opportunities there will be" is an inversion.

Comment: Suppose the first part did not have two "the". For example: "The more skills one has, the greater the opportunities there will be." Here, the mentioned balance does not exist. Is having "the" before "opportunities" still preferred in this case? Or is it better to omit "the" before "opportunities" in this case?

Comment: I should omit it as it sounds better to me without the article. But this is optional rather than a question of correctness.

Comment: Definite article can refer to something that was introduced previously. Can "the opportunities" also refer to "work opportunities" in the previous sentences or it has nothing to do with it? ? Maybe in the last sentence writer wanted to suggest that he is talking about work opportunities and not other kinds of opportunities.

Comment: The second "the" simply marks the NP as definite.